# No Sound In Ubuntu Studio 14.04.1

Tags: sound, ubuntu-studio

When playing video and audio files, or on Youtube, there is not sound output.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was causes by the Volume Control configuration. The wrong audio profile was selected.

To clarify:

In the System settings sound pane, on the output tab, I have multiple outputs. (Digital, and analogue and Headphones).

I had the wrong one selected, and changed it so it now works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing the sound card driver:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui
```

If already installed, then Reinstall the driver package:

```
 sudo apt-get --purge autoremove linux-headers-`uname -r` && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```